# pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid error when finetune wav2vec model with RAVDESS dataset

Tags: python, arrays, pyarrow

I have used ravdess dataset and the model is [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/jonatasgrosman/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-english)

I am trying to predict emotion from speech using this model. I have tried training the model with CREMA, TESS AND SAVEE datasets and all worked fine. I even trained the model on my custom dataset.
But somehow RAVDESS dataset is giving me trouble.
The dataframe has columns name, path and emotions.
This is the error message.

```
Map:   0%|          | 0/1152 [00:00<?, ? examples/s]C:\Users\XTEND\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\transformers\feature_extraction_utils.py:165: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  tensor = as_tensor(value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XTEND\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 3004, in map
    for rank, done, content in Dataset._map_single(**dataset_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\XTEND\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 3397, in _map_single
    writer.write_batch(batch)
  File "C:\Users\XTEND\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_writer.py", line 551, in write_batch
    arrays.append(pa.array(typed_sequence))
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 236, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 110, in pyarrow.lib._handle_arrow_array_protocol
  File "C:\Users\XTEND\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_writer.py", line 186, in __arrow_array__
    out = list_of_np_array_to_pyarrow_listarray(data)
  File "C:\Users\XTEND\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\datasets\features\features.py", line 1395, in list_of_np_array_to_pyarrow_listarray
    return list_of_pa_arrays_to_pyarrow_listarray(
  File "C:\Users\XTEND\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\datasets\features\features.py", line 1388, in list_of_pa_arrays_to_pyarrow_listarray
    values = pa.concat_arrays(l_arr)
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 3039, in pyarrow.lib.concat_arrays
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: arrays to be concatenated must be identically typed, but float and list<item: float> were encountered.
```

This is the code that gave me th error

```
# RAVDESS DATASET
RAV = "D:/program/Audio_SA/Dataset/RAVDESS/"
dir_list = os.listdir(RAV)
print(dir_list.sort())
print(dir_list)

emotion = []
name = []
path = []
for i in dir_list:
    fname = os.listdir(RAV + i)

    for f in fname:
        part = f.split('.')[0].split('-')
        emotion.append(int(part[2]))
        path.append(RAV + i + '/' + f)
        name.append(f)

emotion_df = pd.DataFrame(emotion, columns=['Emotion'])
emotion_df = emotion_df.replace(
    {1: 'neutral', 2: 'neutral', 3: 'happy', 4: 'sad', 5: 'angry', 6: 'fear', 7: 'disgust', 8: 'surprise'})
name_df = pd.DataFrame(name, columns=['Name'])
RAV_df = pd.concat([name_df, pd.DataFrame(path, columns=['Path']), emotion_df], axis=1)
print(RAV_df.head())

# shuffle the DataFrame rows
df = RAV_df.sample(frac=1)
df.to_csv('RAVDESS/Ravdess_df.csv', index=False)

# Filter broken and non-existed paths
print(f"Step 0: {len(df)}")
df["status"] = df["path"].apply(lambda speech_path: True if os.path.exists(speech_path) else None)
df = df.dropna(subset=["path"])
df = df.drop("status", axis=1)
print(f"Step 1: {len(df)}")

df = df.sample(frac=1)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print("labels: ", df["emotion"].unique())
print()
print(df.groupby("emotion").count()[["path"]])

idx = np.random.randint(0, len(df))
sample = df.iloc[idx]
path = sample["path"]
emotion = sample["emotion"]

print(f"ID Location: {idx}")
print(f"      emotion: {emotion}")
print()
print(df.head())
save_path = r"C:\Users\XTEND\PycharmProjects\AER_ENGLISH"
use_auth_token = True
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=101, stratify=df["emotion"])

train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=True)

test_df.to_csv("test_df_new.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
train_df.to_csv("train_df_new.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8", index=False)

print(train_df.shape)
print(test_df.shape)
print(train_df)
print(test_df)


# Prepare Data for Training
# Loading the created dataset using datasets
data_files = {"train": "C:/Users/XTEND/PycharmProjects/custom_AER/RAVDESS/train_df.csv",
              "validation": "C:/Users/XTEND/PycharmProjects/custom_AER/RAVDESS/test_df.csv", }

# data_files = {"train": R"C:\Users\XTEND\PycharmProjects\custom_AER\Main2_files\train_df.csv",
#               "validation": R"C:\Users\XTEND\PycharmProjects\custom_AER\Main2_files\test_df.csv", }

datasets = load_dataset("csv", data_files=data_files, delimiter="\t", )
train_dataset = datasets["train"]
eval_dataset = datasets["validation"]

print(train_dataset)
print(eval_dataset)

# We need to specify the input and output column
input_column = "Path"
output_column = "Emotion"

# we need to distinguish the unique labels in our SER dataset
label_list = train_dataset.unique(output_column)
label_list.sort()  # Let's sort it for determinism
num_labels = len(label_list)
print(f'A classification problem with {num_labels} classes: {label_list}')
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add the code you used to get this error? It looks to me like the different data set don't have the same schema/columns types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and i have edited and provided the code that get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is using tranformers to load or to resample the audio files , use librosa instead of `torchaudio.tranformers.Resample(sr,target_sr)` use librosa code for resampling I think it would work.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will try using librosa and let you know.

Comment: sorry for the late reply this solution worked for me.